# Прямая ссылка на создание новой записи в определенной рубрике на WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Как создать в системе WP ссылку на "Добавить запись" (/post-new.php), нажав на которую откроется редактор новой записи с автоматически проставленной галочкой возле определенной рубрики?

То есть, нажал на ссылку "Добавить запись в рубрике Столы", открывается редактор, и в блоке "Рубрики" галочка возле категории "Столы" уже стоит.

Comment: А как "определённость" рубрики  должна определятся? Можно назначить "рубрику по умолчанию" и тогда с не выбраной рубрикой будут  сыпаться в неё. (жумловод?)

Comment: Рубрика для автопроставления могла бы как-то браться из данных URL, то есть ссылки, по которой переходишь (/post-new.php?postcategory=table). Не знаю, возможно ли это.

Comment: Ок. А в урл предлагаешь ручками писать? :) (в программировании нет "как-то". Должно быть всё чётко.)

Comment: Ссылка будет в админке постоянно висеть, ничего писать не надо. При нажатии - переход к созданию новой записи в категории, которая прописана как-то в url. Но вот как это реализовать не знаю.

Comment: Где " в админке висеть"? Как? Сколько таких "где-то в админке" будет и как этим управлять? Повторяю- программирование - это КОНКРЕТИКА.. Ты сам процесс телодвижений продумал? Пошагово?..Нет..... Ок, ладно - ты хочешь добавить геммора, в то время как в ВП логика оч. простая - основа всему ПОСТ. К нему добавляются связанные данные (рубрики, метки, даты, произвольные поля и тп). Это избавляет от многоходовых путешествий по админке. Читай первый абзац ответа :)

Answer (score 1):

Реализация такого функционала нелогична и сложна, так как до создания поста WP админская панель не знает типа поста, какой вы собираетесь добавить.

Стоит начать с того, как реализованы у вас рубрики, то есть кастомным кодом, через WP, или через плагин (ACF, CPT, Toolset Types, например).

Если плагином (любой, например, из списка выше) то, скорее всего, там уже есть опция указания рубрики по умолчанию.

Если кастомным кодом, то нужно "залезать" в метабокс, и средствами js устанавливать флажок `checked` при загрузке.

Также есть вариант более простой, когда при создании поста, ему автоматически будет установлена категория по умолчанию, если ничего не выбрано в боксе, то есть прикрепить действие проверки, указана ли категория на `save_post`, но это не очень подходит для вашего вопроса, чтобы сразу чекбокс был отмечен.

Есть несколько вариантов решения проблемы, но они все базируются на получении текущей страницы -> проверки типа поста -> установке флажка. Но их реализация очень сложная, так как список категорий в метабоксе выводится в стиле id = "category-1", id = "category-2", id = "category-3" вне зависимости от их имени в БД. То есть, лучше использовать логику, описаную в предыдущем абзаце, но немного модернизированную: после создания поста, проверять тип -> если пост без категории, обновить категорию, базируясь на типе поста.

Или же, подключать js, который работает по принципу (только для кастомных типов постов, так как для обычных URL окна будет без параметров):

1. При загрузке post-new.php из URL окна брать GET параметр `post_type`, например, у вас может быть `post_type=stol`
2. Искать блок с категориями, по умолчанию, он в WP имеет id `category-all`
3. Внутри блока есть список категорий, проходимся по каждой и получаем их значения `.val()`
4. Добавляем условие, если `.val()` = `Столы`, добавляем атрибут `checked`

Минус в том, что придется прибивать все "руками".